# dropdown_search Flutter not returning items when typing into search bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I am using the dropdown_search version 0.4.3 package, I am able to populate the dropdown with items when clicking on the search bar , but when i start typing it isn't returning any items.
I am fetching the initial data from Firebase cloud storage.
Please have a look at my code below.

```
@override
  Widget _buildBody() {
    return OurContainer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          DropdownSearch(
            showSearchBox: true,
            isFilteredOnline: true,
            onFind: (String filter) => getData(filter),
            popupItemBuilder: _customPopupItemBuilderExample,
            dropdownBuilder: _customDropDownExample,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _customDropDownExample(
      BuildContext context, MainCategoryModel item, String itemDesignation) {
    return Container(
      child: (item?.name == null)
          ? ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              title: Text("No item selected"),
            )
          : ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              title: Text(item.name),
            ),
    );
  }

  Widget _customPopupItemBuilderExample(
      BuildContext context, MainCategoryModel item, bool isSelected) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      decoration: !isSelected
          ? null
          : BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
      child: ListTile(
        selected: isSelected,
        title: Text(item.name),
        subtitle: Text(item.name.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }

 



    Future<List<MainCategoryModel>> getData(filter) async {
    final tempList = <MainCategoryModel>[];
    if (filter.length > 0) {
      tempList.addAll(_mainCategoryList
          .where((element) => element.name.toLowerCase().contains(filter)));
      _mainCategoryList.addAll(tempList);
    } else {
      _mainCategoryList.clear();
      _mainCategoryList.addAll(await OurDatabase().getMainCategory());
    }

    return _mainCategoryList;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData` method looks incorrect. Assuming your `_mainCategoryList` is the list from Firebase, the following *synchronous* method should work:

```
List<MainCategoryModel> getData(filter) {
  if (filter.length < 1) {
    return _mainCategoryList;
  }
  return _mainCategoryList.where((element) => element.name.toLowerCase().contains(filter)).toList();
}
```

This method will *not* mutate your `_mainCategoryList`, instead leaving it as a cache so the search will be faster and reduce your read count from Firebase. If this does not do what you need, let me know in the comments below this question and I would be happy to help.

Comment: Hi Gregory, I had to to change the method to a future as the getData in onfind was throwing a error The return type isnt a future. I changed it to get pass the error and was able to on first letter entered return some data but once i entered another letter it returned nothing. Thanks for your help

Comment: it returns nothing means there is something not working well on your filter inside getData. you can change isFilteredOnline to false and everything will be fine (this is not recommanded if you are not loading all the data in your getData result).